# "What should we do IN / FOR the rest of the day?" – can I omit the preposition entirely?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

A very short question: is the following sentence correct?

> What should we do **(...)** the rest of the day?

Could the sentence do without a preposition (in, for), or is one needed?

Comment: Never heard that without a preposition. At times we just go with the flow without any confirmation. That's how we learn those common things.

Comment: @MaulikV Well I have. What now? ( : Although I was only able to find a smattering of results in COCA, I had better luck with the new iWeb corpus.

Comment: @userr2684291 What COCA stands for?

Comment: @RubioRic It stands for [*the Corpus of Contemporary American English*](https://corpus.byu.edu/coca/).

Answer (score 1):

I would say **for** the rest of the day.  You could omit one and your listener would understand but it sounds more correct with it.  You could also use **during** but I would not use **in**.